# Using many / much / a lot of with *population*

Tags: grammar

In an English course book that I use for my Intermediate class, I encountered this problem. The exercise required students to complete the sentences with 'many' or 'much' where possible, otherwise use ' a lot of '. Now, there is this question which I am not sure of its given answer. The question is : Is there ----- population in your country?
The answer from the course book is : 'much'

I have checked the dictionary for the word 'population'. It is an countable noun. Why is the answer 'much' and not ' a lot of ' ? If the answer is 'many', the whole sentence sounds weird to me. Of course, I might be wrong.

Would you please advise me?

Comment: The book's wrong because the question isn't idiomatic English anywhere. StoneyB's & J.R.'s questions are perfectly idiomatic. Another idiomatic possibility: _Is the population in your country large?_ Be wary of language books written by non-native speakers. In Taiwan & Japan, locals who've spent from 6 days to more than 6 years in Anglophone countries think they're qualified to write English books, especially if they have an American MBA. Local publishers use computer programs that blindly replace words in pattern sentences by category w/o knowing that word-usage rules often differ.

Comment: @Part Timer: How do you come to be using such a book in the first place? Do you get to choose the textbooks? If not, who does, with what professed competence?

Comment: Thank you for your answers. The English Course book that I am using is a well-known course book and it is UK system. I dare not to mention the name of the course book here. If you allow, I don't mind to tell you the name of the course book.

Comment: @Part Timer, could it be a typo for "pollution"?

Comment: Cool Elf - you could be right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Population is countable because you can have more than one population. For example, "the populations of England, France, and Spain." But the question isn't asking if there are multiple populations. It's asking if the country has a large population.

I don't think it's a well-worded question, because "much population" is awkward too.

Answer (score 7):

Your book is wrong. The question itself is unidiomatic; in English one would ask "Does your country have a *large* population?"

If the question *were* idiomatic, "Is ... ?" would be your key: *is* takes *much* or *a lot of*, *are* takes *many*.

However, *population* in ordinary usage is not a "countable" noun even though we "count" the population: it is the **name** of the **count** of people. Accordingly, it takes the modifiers we apply to counts and numbers: *large*, *small*, *increasing*, *decreasing*, and so forth.

EDIT:
Kelly Tessena Keck raises a fair point: you may speak of multiple population*s*:

> The population of the US is greater than the populations of Ireland and Germany.

And you may employ *population* as a collective, a synonym of *people*.

> His remarks were offensive to the population of Cincinnati.

But in the context of enumeration, *population* is the result of the count, not the object counted.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're misgivings are justified; I don't think I'd use *much*, *many*, **or** *a lot of* in this case; I'd be more inclined to say:

> *Is there a large population in your country?*

That said, of the three, I do prefer *much* over *many* or *a lot of*.  It's [not unheard of](http://www.google.com/#q=%22is+there+much+population%22&hl=en&prmd=imvnsb&source=lnms&tbm=bks&sa=X&ei=YLM-UM-KH8SXrAGInYDYDg&ved=0CA0Q_AUoBg&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.&fp=1fdbf9716bd9b938&biw=1042&bih=753), but its use is not very widespread.

Comment: Breaking down that *not unheard of* link by century, there's just [one irrelevant false positive](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22quickly+Is+there+much+population+growth%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) in C21, and no hits at all in C19. Of the eight instances in C20, four are duplicates. It's pretty much unheard of, I'd say.